# Make desktop icons always stick on Primary Display in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, icons

I have three monitors, set up like this:

```
\\.\DISPLAY1    2560 X 1440 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970  PG279Q
\\.\DISPLAY2    1920 X 1200 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970  PA246
\\.\DISPLAY3    1920 X 1080 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970  DENON-AVRHD
```

DISPLAY3 is actually a TV, connected through a receiver. They are all connected to the GTX970 through the DP, DVI and HDMI connector respectively. I regularly switch between DISPLAY1 and DISPLAY3 as primary monitor, but never DISPLAY2.

Since DISPLAY3 is in another room, I want *all desktop icons* to always stick on the primary display, and this used to work fine. However, recently they've started being placed on DISPLAY2 instead, and I have to move them manually, which is a chore.

I suspect some Windows update might have bugged this, or something I've done. This is on Windows 10 x64, version 1809.

So my question: Is there a way to ensure desktop icons are *always* placed on the primary monitor, regardless of where Windows *thinks* they belong?